# Extract items from Column in a Dataframe

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

| country_name | rank | show_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 2 | The Queen of Flow |
| India | 1 | Cobra Kai |
| Argentina | 1 | The Queen of Flow |
| England | 3 | Stay Close |
| Argentina | 1 | The Queen of Flow |

I am trying to get a table that will display the number of times each show title is ranked 1st, 2nd or Third. The result something like this:

| Rank | Cobra Kai | The Queen of Flow | Stay Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` like this.

```
df.pivot_table(index=['rank'], columns=['show_title'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

Result

```
           country_name
show_title    Cobra Kai Stay Close The Queen of Flow
rank
1                     1          0                 2
2                     0          0                 1
3                     0          1                 0
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, I appreciate